# Why is a click on a nested element not bubbling up to it's parent with the click binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding, click, event-propagation

I have this HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="action" data-action="foo">
  <h1>Some</h1>
  <p>Text<p>
</a>
```

and this binding:

```
$(document).on("click", ".action", function (e) {
  var do = e.target.getAttribute("data-action");
  if (do === undefined || do === null) {
    console.log("error");
  }
});
```

Strangely if I click on `h1` or `p`, my error logs, while I was expecting the click to bubble up to the link element.

**Question:**
What is the normal behaviour if elements nested inside an element with a click handler are clicked? Why is my click not bubbling up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Strangely if I click on h1 or p, my error logs, while I was expecting the click to bubble up to the link element.

It does (which is why jQuery called your event handler), you're just not looking at that element.

The `target` property of the event object is the element where the event *started* (so, the `h1` or the `p`), not the element on which you've hooked the event, the one that the eventhandler currently running is associated with. With jQuery (and DOM2's `addEventListener`), the element where you've hooked the event is given to you as `this` (and also as `currentTarget` on the event object).

So if you change your `e.target` to `this`, you'll get the behavior you expect.

---

Side note: `do` is a reserved word in JavaScript, you can't use it as a variable name. I'm surprised that code doesn't fail with an error to that effect.

Comment: Interesting. Let me check (and do is reserved... I replaced my long variable name with something shorter. pardon)

Comment: @BakedInhalf: If you want the event to stop bubbling (and possibly triggering other event handlers are ancestor elements), call it. If not, don't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , So lets say I only want a click/tap on a button, and make sure it's not bubbling - I should use e.stopPropagation() ?

Comment: @BakedInhalf: In your handler for the button, yes; otherwise, the event will propagate to the button's parent, then its parent, etc. to the root.